# Upload file to S3 with multer-s3

Tags: node.js, angular, multer, multer-s3

I try to upload file from NodeJS to my S3 bucket.
The next code works fine.

> ./routes/lessons.js

```
 const upload = require('../models/model.lessons');

 router.post('/upload9', upload.array('file', 1), (req, res) => {
        console.log('Uploaded');
        res.send({image: req.file});
    });
```

> ./models/model.lessons.js

```
    const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        acl: 'public-read',
        s3,
        bucket: config.get('AWS.bucket_audios'),
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            req.file = Date.now() + file.originalname;
            cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
        }
    })
})
```

My problem is I want to do additional things before and after uploading.
When I try to move the upload.array inside the model.lessons.js code I got error.
What am I doing wrong ?

> ./routes/lessons.js

```
router.post('/upload', async function (req, res, next) {
try {
    let result = await Lessons.upload2(req, res);
    console.log('uploaded');
    await res.send(result);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json(err);
}
```

});

> ./models/model.lessons.js

```
   upload2: async function (req, res) {

    // some code 

    var result = await multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            acl: 'public-read',
            s3,
            bucket: config.get('AWS.bucket_audios'),
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
                req.file = Date.now() + file.originalname;
                cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
            }
        })
    }).array('file', 1);

    // some code 

    return true;

},
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Hi. Not getting any error. The upload is not executed properly